# PHP Limit string output by specific characters

Tags: php, character, limit, substr

I am trying to limit the number of characters returned from a string using PHP.

I've applied a solution that seems to crash the server (high load / infinite loop), so I am asking for alternative.

I am trying to find a solution that cuts the string and displays the specific number of characters, but still respects the meaning of the sentence, i.e. it does not make a cut in the middle of the word

My function call is as follows:

```
<?php
uc_textcut(get_the_title());
?>
```

And in my functions.php this is the code I used (and it does crash):

```
function uc_textcut($var) {

     $position = 60;
     $result = substr($var,$position,1);

     if ($result !=" ") {
         while($result !=" ") {
            $i = 1;
            $position = $position+$i;
            $result = substr($var,$position,1);
         }
     }

     $result = substr($var,0,$position);
     echo $result;
     echo "...";

}
```

My problem is with `$position = 60`.

The higher that number, the more load it takes -- like its doing a very slow loop.

I imagine something is wrong with `while()`, but I am trying to keep it still understandable by the visitor, again, not cutting in the middle of word.

Any input?

:) thanks very much guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to cut the string, without doing it in the middle of a word, you might consider using the [`wordwrap`](http://www.php.net/wordwrap) function.

It will return a string with lines separated by a newline ; so, you then have to explode that string using \n as a separator, and take the first element of the returned array.

For more informations and/or examples and/or other solutions, see, for instance :

- [How to get first x chars from a string, without cutting off the last word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104306/how-to-get-first-x-chars-from-a-string-without-cutting-off-the-last-word)
- [Making sure PHP substr finishes on a word not a character.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233290/making-sure-php-substr-finishes-on-a-word-not-a-character)
- [Trimming a block of text to the nearest word when a certain character limit is reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708882/trimming-a-block-of-text-to-the-nearest-word-when-a-certain-character-limit-is-re)
- [How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-charac)

Comment: Hmm.. have to say, this is a really smart thinking. thanks for the tip. I applied it..it works fast and it costs one line of code. regards

Comment: @Ahmad : you're welcome :-) ; @Byron : one of the nice things with PHP is that there's always something left to discover ;-) (and that's a reason why I like SO ^^ )

Answer (score 0):

```
    $cutoff = 25;
    if ($i < $cutoff)
    {
        echo $str;
    }
    else
    {
        // look for a space
        $lastSpace = strrchr(substr($str,0,$cutoff)," ");
        echo substr($str,0,$lastspace);
        echo "...";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will cut off at either 60 characters or the first space after 60 characters, identical to your initial code but far more efficient:

```
$position = 60;
if(substr($var,$position,1) == " ") $position = strpos($var," ",$position);

if($position == FALSE) $result = $var;
else $result = substr($var,0,$position);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/(^.{60,}?) /', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Then you have to add the ellipses if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// same as phantombrain's but in a function
function uc_textcut($text) {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/(^.{60,}?) /', $text, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1])) {
        echo $matches[1] . "...";
    } else {
        echo $text;
    }
}


// test it
$textLong = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempus dui non sapien ullamcorper vel tincidunt nisi cursus. Vestibulum ultrices pharetra justo id varius.';
$textShort = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';

uc_textcut($textLong);
echo "\n";
uc_textcut($textShort);
```

?>

Prints:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```