# Shortening a string with ... on the end

Tags: php, string, truncate

Is there an official PHP function to do this?  What is this action called?

Comment: Some call it truncating, some call it excerpting... but sadly PHP has no built-in function for this :(

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446034

Comment: What's wrong with `$string = substr($string, 0, 50) . '...';`?

Comment: That you need `if (strlen($string) > 50) { $string = substr($string, 0, 47)."..."; }`.

Comment: @Jonah, that works, but also cuts off words.  Just something to be cautious of, especially on corporate sites. ;)

Comment: @simshaun: Then see my first comment.

Comment: PHP isn't intended to do this. CSS is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in function, but you can of course build your own:

```
function str_truncate($str, $length) {
   if(strlen($str) <= $length) return $str;
   return substr($str, 0, $length - 3) . '...';
}
```

Comment: Some strings, when lacking the last three chars, will end in a space. This isn't desired, since you don't want your "..." appearing as " ..." Something that should be considered. Other than that, +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
function truncateWords($input, $numwords, $padding="") {
    $output = strtok($input, " \n");
    while(--$numwords > 0) $output .= " " . strtok(" \n");
    if($output != $input) $output .= $padding;
    return $output;
}
```

Truncate by word

Answer (score 1):

No, PHP does not have a function built-in to "truncate" strings (unless some weird extension has one, but it's not guaranteed the viewers/you will have that sort of plugin -- I don't know of any that do).

I would recommend just writing a simple function for it, something like:

```
<?php

function truncate($str, $len)
{
  if(strlen($str) <= $len) return $str;
  $str = substr($str, 0, $len) . "...";
  return $str;
}

?>
```

And if you'd like to use a "suspension point" character (a single character with the three dots; it's unicode), use the HTML entity `&hellip;`.

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of [wordwrap](http://php.net/wordwrap), [substr](http://php.net/substr) and [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) to make sure it doesn't cut off words, or that the delimiter is not preceded by a space.

```
function truncate($str, $length, $delimiter = '...') {
   $ww = wordwrap($str, $length, "\n");
   return substr($ww, 0, strpos($ww, "\n")).$delimiter;
}

$str = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
echo truncate($str, 25); 
// outputs 'The quick brown fox...' 
// as opposed to 'The quick brown fox jumpe...' when using substr() only
```