# How do I cut a string and add suspension marks?

Tags: php

I wan to cut a string in around 300 characters and add "..." at the end if it was above that number of characters. I know it can't be very hard but I don't want to cut a word in half so I wanted to know how do I do it so it doesn't end up like: "And the bird suddenl..."

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446034

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars)

Comment: more: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=truncate+string+word+boundary+php

Comment: *(sidenote)* An ellipsis is not `...` but `…` or `&hellip;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/wordwrap

```
$str = 'A very long string here';
$str = wordwrap($str, 100);
$str = explode("\n", $str);
$str = $str[0] . '...';
```

Comment: Nope. Try with `"is simply dummy \ntext of the printing and"`

Comment: We can use `$str = str_replace("\n",'',$str);` at the beginning... Is it ??

Comment: What if the OP wants to stay newlines intact? You dont know if the resulting string is printed in a browser where newlines are not shown anyway. It could be printed in a shell environment and there it would be meaningful.

Comment: OP may want many other things also. OP is allowed to play with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
function limit($str, $limit, $append = '...') {
    return preg_replace('/\S*$/', '', mb_substr($str, 0, $limit)) . $append;
}
```