# List Title But End At Last Word

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site where I am listing titles, and since each title is larger than our needed space I have to use the following code to break it down if it is larger than a certain amount of characters, and then show ...:

```
<?php $title = get_the_title(); echo mb_strimwidth($title, 0, 45, '...'); ?>
```

Is there a way to possibly list only a certain amount of words, instead of characters, so we can at least have a full word at the end of the title instead of a character and then ...?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is on a WP system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using multi-byte string functions, you can do:

```
if (mb_strlen($title) > 45) {
    $title = mb_substr($title, 0, 45);
    // make sure it ends in a word by chomping at last space
    $title = mb_substr($title, 0, mb_strrpos($title, " ")).'...';
}

echo $title;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use [wordwrap()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function and then discard all lines except the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common question, asked and answered many times on SO. Here are two solutions:

[Trim headline to nearest word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446034/trim-headline-to-nearest-word)
[Trimming a block of text to the nearest word when a certain character limit is reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708882/trimming-a-block-of-text-to-the-nearest-word-when-a-certain-character-limit-is-re)