# Limiting the output of PHP's echo to 200 characters

Tags: php

I'm trying to limit my PHP `echo` to only 200 characters and then if there are any more replace them with `"..."`.

How could I modify the following statement to allow this?

```
<?php echo $row['style-info'] ?>
```

Comment: wouldnt it be easier to create a custom function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trimming a block of text to the nearest word when a certain character limit is reached?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708882/trimming-a-block-of-text-to-the-nearest-word-when-a-certain-character-limit-is-re)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662165/7186739

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Well, you could make a custom function:

```
function custom_echo($x, $length)
{
  if(strlen($x)<=$length)
  {
    echo $x;
  }
  else
  {
    $y=substr($x,0,$length) . '...';
    echo $y;
  }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
<?php custom_echo($row['style-info'], 200); ?>
```

Comment: This takes way to much space :)

Comment: @Luka, But it's a function and a readable one, while our solutions were one-liners for one time use only

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response sorry i don't know PHP well enough, where in that statement do i tell it to echo ['style-info']?

Comment: What do you mean by `'style_info'`?

Comment: I'm trying to echo out the contents of a field ['style-info'] from my mysql table but limit it to 200 characters.

Comment: Okay, then run all of the strings from the table through the `custom_echo` function above.  The function doesn't care whether or not its input comes from a database.

Comment: Thanks Jack, so simple & handy function.

Answer (score 40):

Not sure why no one mentioned this before -

```
echo mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...");
// output: "Hello W..."
```

More info check - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php

Answer (score 21):

Like this:

```
echo substr($row['style-info'], 0, 200);
```

Or wrapped in a function:

```
function echo_200($str){
    echo substr($row['style-info'], 0, 200);
}

echo_200($str);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php echo substr($row['style_info'], 0, 200) .((strlen($row['style_info']) > 200) ? '...' : ''); ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

It gives out a string of max 200 characters OR 200 normal characters OR 200 characters followed by '...'

```
$ur_str= (strlen($ur_str) > 200) ? substr($ur_str,0,200).'...' :$ur_str;
```

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me and it's also very easy

```
<?php

$position=14; // Define how many character you want to display.

$message="You are now joining over 2000 current"; 
$post = substr($message, 0, $position); 

echo $post;
echo "..."; 

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
    if(strlen($var) > 200){
        echo substr($var,0,200) . " ...";
    }
    else{
        echo $var;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is most easy way for doing that

```
//substr(string,start,length)
substr("Hello Word", 0, 5);
substr($text, 0, 5);
substr($row['style-info'], 0, 5);
```

for more detail

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

more flexible way is a function with two parameters:

```
function lchar($str,$val){return strlen($str)<=$val?$str:substr($str,0,$val).'...';}
```

usage:

```
echo lchar($str,200);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function TitleTextLimit($text,$limit=200){
 if(strlen($text)<=$limit){
    echo $text;
 }else{
    $text = substr($text,0,$limit) . '...';
    echo $text;
 }
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation of why and how this code answers the question. It would be much more useful than just this wordless dump of code.

Comment: I fixed the formatting, also naming of function is not best. It's not better then first answer too.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo strlen($row['style-info']) > 200) ? substr($row['style-info'], 0, 200)."..." : $row['style-info'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo strlen($row['style-info'])<=200 ? $row['style-info'] : substr($row['style-info'],0,200).'...';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
echo ((strlen($row['style-info']) > 200) ? substr($row['style-info'],0,200).'...' : $row['style-info']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code we define a method and then we can simply call it. we give it two parameters. first one is text and the second one should be count of characters that you wanna display.

```php
function the_excerpt(string $text,int $length){
    if(strlen($text) > $length){$text = substr($text,0,$length);}
    return $text; 
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code: What does it do, how does it work, and how does it solve OPs problem. Code only answers can lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and you risk getting downvotes.