# How do i limit characters echoed from database?

Tags: php, mysql, character, limit, dreamweaver

I've made a "news" section on my website, and I'm trying to make a little box on my template to the right which echos latest news (title, text and author). My problem is that I only wish to echo about 20 characters from "text" in the little box.

I'm using dreamweaver, and i'm horrible at php. Here's the code. It's the "tekst" field i wan't to limit to 20 characters.

```
<?php do { ?>
<h1><?php echo $row_posts['tittel']; ?></h1>
<p class="posttekst">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_posts['tekst']; ?></p>
<p><em><?php echo $row_posts['forfatter']; ?> <?php echo $row_posts['dato']; ?></em></p>
<hr />
<?php } while ($row_posts = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts)); ?>
```

It's in norwegian - `tittel : title`, `tekst: text`, `forfatter: author`, `dato:date`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try  `substr($row_posts['tittel'],0,20);`

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/php-cut-a-string-after-x-characters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662165/7186739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `substr()` is what you're looking for: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

`<?php echo substr($row_posts['tekst'], 0, 20); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$newstext = substr($row_posts['tekst'], 0, strrpos(substr($row_posts['tekst'], 0, 20), ' '));
```

The above code will truncate any string to the nearest whole word, while staying under the maximum string length.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this one aswell!